# Demoiselle Erro ao fazer deploy no JBoss

Tags: java, maven, jboss, demoiselle

Ao tentar fazer deploy da aplicação de exemplo, inscrição, dos tutoriais do Demoiselle no JBoss, obtive o seguinte erro:

```
11:34:16,873 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."inscricao.war#inscricao-teste-ds": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."inscricao.war#inscricao-teste-ds": Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: inscricao-teste-ds] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2266)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1735)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
    ... 9 more
```

O erro ocorre no modulo 7 apos modificar o POM para JSF. Abaixo o POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.djsystem</groupId>
    <artifactId>inscricao</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name></name>
    <description></description>
    <url></url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
        <artifactId>demoiselle-jsf-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.component</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoiselle-junit</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoiselle-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Na log está aparecendo: `inscricao-teste-ds` que é a PU de testes que deve estar em `/src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` que não deveria aparecer no deploy. O próprio Eclipse+Maven fariam esse controle. Talvez um "clean no projeto resolva" e na pior hipótese pode até apagar ou renomear esse arquivo que não deveria estar "empacotado" no projeto.
- Também verifique o arquivo `persistence.xml` que deverá estar na pasta: `src/main/resources/META-INF/`, na falta dele pode ser que o outro tenha sido utilizado.

Answer (score 0):

Este problema foi resolvido. Mas surgiu um novo ao fazer deploy de uma outra aplicação desta vez um exemplo utilizando o Vaadin:

```
11:47:56,436 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 17) JBAS014612: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "vaadintest.war")]): java.util.NoSuchElementException: No child 'runtime-name' exists
    at org.jboss.dmr.ModelValue.requireChild(ModelValue.java:362) [jboss-dmr-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.dmr.ObjectModelValue.requireChild(ObjectModelValue.java:298) [jboss-dmr-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.dmr.ModelNode.require(ModelNode.java:812) [jboss-dmr-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentDeployHandler.execute(DeploymentDeployHandler.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:385) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:272) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:200) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.CompositeOperationHandler.execute(CompositeOperationHandler.java:85) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:385) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:272) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:200) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$DefaultPrepareStepHandler.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:466) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:385) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:272) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:200) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:121) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.doExecute(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:139) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1.execute(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:108) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler$2$1.doExecute(AbstractMessageHandler.java:287) [jboss-as-protocol-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler$AsyncTaskRunner.run(AbstractMessageHandler.java:487) [jboss-as-protocol-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.0.0.GA.jar:2.0.0.GA]
```

O persistence.xml está no local indicado na resposta anterior, seu conteúdo é:

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

```
<!-- JBoss6 ou JBoss7 -->
    <persistence-unit name="bookmark-ds" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <non-jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSqlDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <class>br.com.djsystem.domain.Bookmark</class>
        <class>br.com.djsystem.domain.Category</class>
        <class>br.com.djsystem.domain.Banco</class>
        <class>br.com.djsystem.domain.ContaCorrente</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 0):

Está parecendo problema de ambiente (windows+eclipse) no último erro. Melhor se postar a log toda do console do Jboss no Eclipse. Tem um detalhe no datasource que pode não ter nada a ver com o erro. Mas pode dar outro problema: no java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSqlDS.  Pelo nome parece que você está usando o Postgresql como banco de dados e na linha property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" é o dialeto do H2. Se for postgresql seria: property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"